# How to query select multiple columns if columns <>'' and Col1 contains "string"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

Import From Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw/edit?usp=sharing

Import To Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6gHMv_R8sipeY7PbLbgLYde2o66NM-v-_KL8k_mmug/edit?usp=sharing

Import From Sheet: [image]

Import To Sheet: [image]

I'm trying to Select Multiple cells imported into 1 column in order if this criteria is met:

```
Col1 = Maintenance:
Col3 is not <>''
Col12 is not <>''
Col21 is not <>''
Col30 is not <>''
```

Having some trouble removing the blank cells with my query though.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 1-4'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 5-8'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 9-12'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 13-16'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 17-20'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 21-24'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 25-28'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 29-32'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 33-36'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 37-40'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 41-44'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 45-48'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1-CDuKq2ueygE8qLdV6EH1eeXT9NSYYG8N_k4XqDEtdw","'Week 49-52'!B97:AL162")},
"SELECT Col3, Col12, Col21, Col30 where Col1 contains 'Maintenance:' and Col3, Col12, Col21, Col30 is not <>''"))
```

Comment: Did Player0 answer solved your problem? Could you provide a sample of what you are trying to do? Maybe what you are trying to achieve is very specific for your case and a more generic example could be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't gotten it to work, I provided links to sample sheets.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do it like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 1-4'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 5-8'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 9-12'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 13-16'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 17-20'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 21-24'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 25-28'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 29-32'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 33-36'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 37-40'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 41-44'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 45-48'!B97:AL162");
Importrange("1Pf4NwDDpKnRcn16SPNwpIJsJZMB0ISfOtpsaIkaiZwM","'Week 49-52'!B97:AL162")},
"select Col3,Col12,Col21,Col30 
 where Col1 contains 'Maintenance:' 
   and Col3 is not null
   and Col12 is not null
   and Col21 is not null
   and Col30 is not null"))
```

or use `or` instead of `and` if needed

[image: 0]

Comment: I tried this before also but it returns
"Error
Query completed with an empty output."

If I run it on only Col12, it returns correctly (rest are empty/null).

Comment: did you try with OR ?

Comment: Sorry, yes i did try with OR & AND.  Provided links to sheets now also.

Comment: can you provide example of desired output?

Comment: Updated Desired Output Image and in shared sheets.

Comment: For me player0 solution is working, take a look at your sheets. If it still doesn't work maybe you could try to clarify more what you want to get.

Comment: @PeterChabot isnt thiis what you want? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYRuL.png or this? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pATpN.png